# Change data at specific condition in sequelize

Tags: database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using PostgreSQL with sequelize on Javascript project. It is about managing project schedule and I want to update my data on specific condition. For example

1. There is one Project with 'due_date' and 'current_status'.
2. If I set 'due_date' then 'current_status' become 'ongoing'.
3. When current date passes 'due_date', then 'current_status' should become 'delayed'.

I want to make `step 3` automatically, but I have no idea where to handle. Currently I am looking for hooks but I can not find any hooks that can satisfy it. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to schedule a job to actively look for rows that need updating.

The job can be fired by some external scheduler (e.g. cron) or by the pg_cron extension if you're able to install it.